# How to calculate an equation using eval-parse in R?

Tags: r, parsing, eval

How do I calculate the value of an equation using eval parse in R? The value for each component of the equation should be taken from the eponymously named columns within the same row e.g. 'alpha' from column 'alpha' and so on.

Dataframe:

```
dput(<alpha beta    gamma   delta   epsilon zeta    eta theta   RF  min.speed.kph   max.speed.kph   speed   equation
9.70E-05    0.0026  1.432   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  130 30  ((alpha*speed^2)+(beta*speed)+gamma+(delta*log10(speed))+(epsilon*exp(zeta*speed))+(eta*(speed^theta)))*(1-RF)
7.40E-05    0.013   1.484   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  130 30  ((alpha*speed^2)+(beta*speed)+gamma+(delta*log10(speed))+(epsilon*exp(zeta*speed))+(eta*(speed^theta)))*(1-RF)
0.000266    -0.014  2.427   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  130 30  ((alpha*speed^2)+(beta*speed)+gamma+(delta*log10(speed))+(epsilon*exp(zeta*speed))+(eta*(speed^theta)))*(1-RF)
2.88E-12    2.56E-10    -2.09E-07   7.75E-05    -0.005274381    0.152658622 0   0.88    NA  10  140 30  ((alpha*speed^5)+beta*speed^4+gamma*speed^3+delta*speed^2+epsilon*speed+zeta)*(theta)
2.88E-12    2.56E-10    -2.09E-07   7.75E-05    -0.005274381    0.152658622 0   0.6 NA  10  140 30  ((alpha*speed^5)+beta*speed^4+gamma*speed^3+delta*speed^2+epsilon*speed+zeta)*(theta)
0.524738843 0   -0.01   0   9.36E-05    0   0   0   0   5   130 30  ((alpha+gamma*speed+epsilon*speed^2+zeta/speed)/(1+beta*speed+delta*speed^2))*(1-RF)
0.283553945 -0.0234 -0.00869    0.000443    0.000114    0   0   0   0   5   130 30  ((alpha+gamma*speed+epsilon*speed^2+zeta/speed)/(1+beta*speed+delta*speed^2))*(1-RF)
0.189162424 1.571506423 0.081547506 0.027327758 -0.000248892    -0.268467236    0   0   0   5   130 30  (alpha+gamma*speed+epsilon*speed^2+zeta/speed)/(1+beta*speed+delta*speed^2)
0.474232144 5.621746462 0.340577763 0.083762882 -0.001515827    -1.191086695    0   0   0   5   130 30  (alpha+gamma*speed+epsilon*speed^2+zeta/speed)/(1+beta*speed+delta*speed^2)
0.189162424 1.571506423 0.081547506 0.027327758 -0.000248892    -0.268467236    0   0   0   5   130 30  (alpha+gamma*speed+epsilon*speed^2+zeta/speed)/(1+beta*speed+delta*speed^2)
>)
```

I have tried this but it's not working:

`nox.file$calculated_col <- eval(parse(text=as.character(nox.file$equation)), nox.file)`

I have also tried wrapping it in 'mutate' to help with vectorising it but neither does this work:

`nox.file <- nox.file %>% mutate(calculated_col=eval(parse(text=as.character(equation)), nox.file))`

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: For starters, R's parser won't know that `alphaspeed` really means `alpha * speed`.

Comment: Thanks for flagging @MikaelJagan. My copy-paste appears to have not worked properly. Yes please assume that alphaspeed is `alpha*speed` and betaspeed is `beta*speed` and so on.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the output of `dput(<data frame>)` into your question, so that we can construct your data frame in R? Then you can delete this block of text.

Comment: I've just tried but I don't think I'm doing it right...the "*" are missing yet again. Sorry I'm a new user!

Comment: Just put `dput(nox.file[1:5, ])` into R and copy/paste what comes out into the window. The result should start with `structure(`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is that `eval` is not vectorized. It only evaluates the last element of the expression vector `parse(text = equation)`. You can try something like this instead:

```r
library("dplyr")

dd <- nox.file %>% 
    group_by(equation) %>%
    ## mutate(calculated_col = eval(str2lang(cur_group()[[1L]])))
    mutate(calculated_col = tryCatch(eval(str2lang(cur_group()[[1L]])), error = function(e) NA_real_))

dd$calculated_col
## [1] 1.59730000 1.94060000 2.24640000 0.05175415 0.03528692
## [6] 0.30897884 0.18006882 0.03303038 0.03790261 0.03303038
```

I reconstructed `nox.file` from your copy and paste like so:

```r
x <- "alpha beta    gamma   delta   epsilon zeta    eta theta   RF  min.speed.kph   max.speed.kph   speed   equation
9.70E-05    0.0026  1.432   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  130 30  ((alpha*speed^2)+(beta*speed)+gamma+(delta*log10(speed))+(epsilon*exp(zeta*speed))+(eta*(speed^theta)))*(1-RF)
7.40E-05    0.013   1.484   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  130 30  ((alpha*speed^2)+(beta*speed)+gamma+(delta*log10(speed))+(epsilon*exp(zeta*speed))+(eta*(speed^theta)))*(1-RF)
0.000266    -0.014  2.427   0   0   0   0   0   0   10  130 30  ((alpha*speed^2)+(beta*speed)+gamma+(delta*log10(speed))+(epsilon*exp(zeta*speed))+(eta*(speed^theta)))*(1-RF)
2.88E-12    2.56E-10    -2.09E-07   7.75E-05    -0.005274381    0.152658622 0   0.88    NA  10  140 30  ((alpha*speed^5)+beta*speed^4+gamma*speed^3+delta*speed^2+epsilon*speed+zeta)*(theta)
2.88E-12    2.56E-10    -2.09E-07   7.75E-05    -0.005274381    0.152658622 0   0.6 NA  10  140 30  ((alpha*speed^5)+beta*speed^4+gamma*speed^3+delta*speed^2+epsilon*speed+zeta)*(theta)
0.524738843 0   -0.01   0   9.36E-05    0   0   0   0   5   130 30  ((alpha+gamma*speed+epsilon*speed^2+zeta/speed)/(1+beta*speed+delta*speed^2))*(1-RF)
0.283553945 -0.0234 -0.00869    0.000443    0.000114    0   0   0   0   5   130 30  ((alpha+gamma*speed+epsilon*speed^2+zeta/speed)/(1+beta*speed+delta*speed^2))*(1-RF)
0.189162424 1.571506423 0.081547506 0.027327758 -0.000248892    -0.268467236    0   0   0   5   130 30  (alpha+gamma*speed+epsilon*speed^2+zeta/speed)/(1+beta*speed+delta*speed^2)
0.474232144 5.621746462 0.340577763 0.083762882 -0.001515827    -1.191086695    0   0   0   5   130 30  (alpha+gamma*speed+epsilon*speed^2+zeta/speed)/(1+beta*speed+delta*speed^2)
0.189162424 1.571506423 0.081547506 0.027327758 -0.000248892    -0.268467236    0   0   0   5   130 30  (alpha+gamma*speed+epsilon*speed^2+zeta/speed)/(1+beta*speed+delta*speed^2)"

con <- textConnection(x)
nox.file <- read.table(con, header = TRUE)
close(con)
```

The reconstruction may not be exact, which is why you are encouraged to include proper `dput` output in your question.

Comment: Unfortunately I get this error: Problem with 'mutate()' input 'calculated_col', parsing result not of length one, but 0, Input 'calculated_col' is ` eval(str2lang(cur_group()[[1L]])))`, the error occurred in group 1: equation = " ".

Comment: It seems to work for up to 40+ rows but fails at 50. My data table has 380 rows. Is there any way to sort this without splitting up the data into chunks?

Comment: The problem seems to be that one of the expressions in `nox.file$equation` is empty, i.e., `" "`. You have to fix that on your end or explain what you'd like to happen in this case. You need to group by `equation` because you can only evaluate one expression at a time. This approach is vectorized "per expression", which is the best you can do...

Comment: I've updated the answer. Now `calculated_col` is `NA` when `equation` cannot be evaluated, including when `equation = " "`.

Comment: Fantastic, this now works! Thanks so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
df %>% 
   rowwise() %>%
   mutate(sol = eval(parse(text = equation)))
```